# RemoteFx 3d Video Adapter does not appear in Hyper-V R2 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v

Im running Windows Server 2012 R2 with the Hyper-V role. In the Hyper-V configuration, I was able to select the card I want to use with RemoteFX. I made the virtual machine (without installing anything to the actual virtual machine) BUT when I try to add hardware and add the RemoteFx 3d Video Adapter, it does not appear.

Ive tried it thru Powershell as well and Powershell gives me a error similar to "Hyper-V cannot find the S3 driver".

The card is a Quadro K2200 and it has the latest drivers installed on the host from nVidia.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go....got the answer.  When You are creating the VM, you must choose "Gen1" not gen2 vm type..... even if you intend to use Win 8.1 ent.

M